How can I run a subquery with leftJoinAndMap
Here are my entities
Channel Entity
@Entity({ name: 'channels' })
export class Channel extends BaseEntity {
  @Index()
  @Column({ name: 'topic', unique: true, nullable: true })
  topic: string;

  @Column({ name: 'description', nullable: true })
  description: string;

  @Column({ name: 'is_deleted', type: 'boolean', default: false })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @Column({ name: 'is_group', type: 'boolean', default: false })
  isGroup: boolean;

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (message) => message.channel)
  channelMessages: Message[];

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.channelsCreated)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'created_by' })
  createdBy: User;

  @OneToMany(() => ChannelUser, (channelUser) => channelUser.channel, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  users: ChannelUser[];

  latestMessage : Message;
}

Message Entity
@Entity({ name: 'messages' })
export class Message extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ name: 'content' })
  content: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.sentMessages)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'sender_id' })
  sender: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Channel, (channel) => channel.channelMessages)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'channel_id' })
  channel: Channel;

  @Column({ name: 'is_deleted', type: 'boolean', default: false })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @Column({
    name: 'status',
    type: 'enum',
    enum: MessageStatusEnum,
    default: MessageStatusEnum.SENT,
  })
  status: MessageStatusEnum;

  @OneToMany(() => MessageStatus, (messageStatus) => messageStatus.message)
  readMessages: MessageStatus[];
}


I am trying to run this query to get all the channels along with latestMessage sent in each channel to be mapped to latestMessage property of the channel entity
    const channels = this.channelRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('c')
      .innerJoinAndMapOne(
        'c.latestMessage',
        (sub) => {
          return sub
            .from(Message, 'm')
            .orderBy({ 'm.createdAt': 'DESC' })
            .limit(1);
        },
        'latestMessage',
        'latestMessage.channel = c.id',
      );

    return channels.getMany();

However, I get the following error:

QueryFailedError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "latestmessage"

I have assigned an alias for the subquery as latestMessage, so why does it show that I can't select from it?

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

The entities images were just for reference.
